# How to remove or replace Alphabets from specific position in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the Alphabets "Country Names" and bracket "()" from my Country Code selection drop-down menu. but the problem is I can't find the perfect match REGEX for this.

```html
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+93)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"></span> India (+91)
```

```js
replace(/[()A-Za-z]{45,100}/g, '');
```

This pattern is also removing the alphabets of my  tag which creates problem for me because the span tag contain SVG country flag icons, for this I want to remove the alphabets from 45th position and remove only the country names and () after selecting a drop-down option.

Output I'm getting -

Flag-icon Country-Name +93
(It just removing the brackets not country name)

Output I want -

Flag-icon +93

```js
DATA.replace(/[()A-Za-z]{45,100}/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an exact offset to start the match, you could capture the ` tag in the current data in group 1, and capture the format of the number between parenthesis in group 2.

The use those 2 groups in the replacement.

```
(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+\d+)\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)` Capture from `<span>...</span>` in **group 1**
- `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*` Match word chars optionally repeated by spaces and word chars
- `\(` Match `(`

  - `(\+\d+)` Capture `+` and 1+ digits in **group 2**
- `\)` Match `)`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZVorgX/1) with the capture group data.

```js
const regex = /(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+\d+)\)/g;
const str = `<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+93)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"></span> India (+91)`;

console.log(str.replace(regex, `$1$2`));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your pattern is exactly matching my requirements.

Comment: But i need little more help, some countries also have "-" in their country code i.e, Isle of Man (+44-1624) and Bahamas (+1-242). which is not working with this regex pattern, because it have a "-" also, can you help me about this

Comment: @GupaDutta In that case the pattern could be `(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+[\d-]+)\)` See https://regex101.com/r/XSVxyu/1

Comment: Sir I have also added a option named "No Data Found" to show just after the Search Box when no Country Name found in Search Result. and the problem is this REGEX is also accepting the "No Data Found" text as a string as selected option. I want to disallow this specific text "No Data Found" in my REGEX pattern. Can you please guide me little more.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dropdowns using always <span class=" but dynamic classes and country codes, this REGEX does the trick for you:

```js
const input = `<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+93)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"></span> India (+91)`;

console.log(input.replace(/(<[^>]+>[^>]+>)\s\w+\s\((\+\d+)\)/g, '$1$2'));
```

Output:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span>+93
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span>+880
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"></span>+91
```

Real live working:

```js
const input = `<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+93)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"></span> India (+91)`;

console.log(input.replace(/<[^>]+>[^>]+>\s\w+\s\((\+\d+)\)/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: Thank you but your code is returning flag-icon as a string, but I mean to say that... Not include the Span tag in REGEX filter, leave the span tag as it is, because it will render the flag svg.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're facing is that you're trying to remove characters around a thing instead of just matching that thing, which would be an easier task where you could use regex capture groups. Not sure I fully understood the inputs and outputs but for each row you could do:

```
const formatRow = (input) => {
  const flagMatch = input.match(/flag-icon-\w+/);
  const flag = flagMatch && flagMatch[0];

  const numberMatch = input.match(/\((.*)\)/);
  const number = numberMatch && numberMatch[1]; // 1 is index of capture group

  return `${flag} ${number}`
}

// e.g
formatRow('<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+93)'); // output: 'flag-icon-afg +93'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a global `.replace()` that looks for the end tag `>` symbol, and removes everything not needed:

```js
let html = $('div').html();
html = html.replace(/>.*?\((.*?)\)/g, '> $1');
console.log(html);
$('div').html(html)
```

```css
.flag-icon::before {
  content: "\A▚ ";
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+93)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"></span> India (+91)
</div>
```

Output:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"> +93
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"> +880
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ind"> +91
```